# Calculate the SD in a different dataset with different data value limits

Tags: r

I am a beginner with R and want to calculate the SD of values in another dataframe several times within limits of values in a dataframe.
Imagine I have a dataframe looking like this.

```
peak     <- c("max", "max", "max")
value    <- c(42, 105, 170)
minbefore<- c(20, 50, 115)
minafter <- c(50, 115, 180)
extrema  <- data.frame(peak, value, minbefore, minafter)
```

I now want to calculate the SD of the values in another dataframe `em$Position`  within the limits of `extrema$minbefore`and `extrema$minafter` for each row of the dataframe `extreme`.

My idea was something like this

`extrema$SD <- sd(em$Position[em$Position>extrema$minbefore & em$Position<extrema$minafter])`

Then I get the following error message: `longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length`

Which absolutely makes sense to me because I assume that R probably tries to insert the whole vector `extrema$minbefore` and `extrema$minafter` resepectively and at the same time which obviuosly makes no sense.

What would be the right way to do it?

Thanks in advance.
Dominik.

Comment: Do you have four columns in your dataframe? Code above gives me one long column so wanted to clarify. Thanks.

Comment: @mysteRious sorry, the code was wrong. I did correct it so now it should work. I have four columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `apply` function to do this:

```
# dummy data
em <- data.frame(Position = unlist(as.integer(runif(n = 30, min = 20, max = 190))))

# function to calculate sd
extrema$SD <- apply(extrema[,c('minbefore','minafter')], 1, function(x){

    return( sd(em[(em$Position > x[1]) & (em$Position < x[2]),'Position']))

})

print(extreme)
   peak value minbefore minafter        SD
1  max    42        20       50   5.966574
2  max   105        50      115   19.07878
3  max   170       115      180  18.407426
```

**Explanation:**

- We traverse through each row of `extreme`, get the min and max values.
- Using min, max values, we subset the `em$Position` and calculate the `sd`.

Comment: Thank you, that helped a lot!

Comment: Sorry, just for me to understand: what does the part `(em$Position > x[1]) ...` in the return() command mean (I understand that it's a logic statement but why `x[1]` and `x[2]` later on)? Do `1` and `2` stand for the `extrema$minbefore` and `extrema$minafter` and if so, why?

Comment: @DominikGrätz Yes, you are right. 1 refers to column `minbefore` and 2 refers to `minafter`.